# react render twice!!! how can i stop re-render?

Tags: reactjs, rerender

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';
/*
import {Component} from 'react';等同於
import React from 'react';
const Component=React.Component;
*/
import {Fragment} from 'react';
/*
Fragment為佔位符,使用他的原因是因為JSX語法僅能接受一個tag包裹所有其他tag,若是使用div包裹,則在
瀏覽器渲染時會多出多餘的div標籤,而使用Fragment於瀏覽器渲染時不會有該標籤的顯示
*/
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
//將子組件引入

class TodoList extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={//當組件中的state或props發生改變時,render函式就會重新執行
            inputValue:'hello there',
            list:[]
        };
        this.inputValueChange=this.inputValueChange.bind(this);  /* bind(this)綁定函數的作用域 */
        this.addList=this.addList.bind(this);
        this.delList=this.delList.bind(this);
    }
    render(){
        console.log('todoList test');
        return(
        <Fragment>
            <input 
                value={this.state.inputValue}//在JSX語法中使用JS的表達式(變數或方法)時需要用{}包裹,像input/ul等皆為JSX一般語法
                onChange={this.inputValueChange}            
            />
            <button onClick={this.addList}>按鈕</button>
            <ul>
                {this.getTodoItem()}               
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
        );
    }
```

QA:
hello~everyone~
I have a little trouble on how to avoid re-render.
I found render function would be executed twice after state was changed.
How can I improve the situation and why this event would happen?

Comment: In that code there is nothing that can provides information about your issue. Just the this.getTodoItem() function call if it is updating your state or just the parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is probably rendering twice due to [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). You can disable this setting:

Check whether your `app` is wrapped by `<React.StrictMode>` in your index.js:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {app}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If so, you can disable *StrictMode* by removing the `<React.StrictMode>` tag:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  {app},
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```